# Hyper-V 2012 R2 x64 UpdateID

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, wsus-offline

I'm trying to write a powershell script in order to manage my updates for multiple Hyper-V 2012 R2 machines. To problem i stumbled upon is that i am unable to find the updateId for it so i can manage the hotfixes/updates i download.

To be more clearly, i use the standalone hypervisor, not a Windows Server 2012 R2 with an added role of hyper-v server.

Does it have the same UpdateId as Windows Server 2012R2 ? Is it possible ?

Thanks.